# C Program: How to set custom integer range, strictly limiting the accepted input numbers within that range only?

Tags: c, int, range, limit

Let's consider a case where a program has to take a number as an input from the user, only within a strict range of any between 1 and 10,00,000,000? Is it possible in C? If yes, it would be nice if someone can explain this by making modifications to following example program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned long int n, e1,e2,e3;
    int counter;

    for(counter=0; counter<10; counter++)
    {

        scanf("%ld",&n); // how to restrict this between 1 to 10,000,000,000?

        e1=n/2;
        e2=n/3;
        e3=n/4;

        if(e1+e2+e3<n)
        {
            printf("%ld\n",n);
        }

        else

            printf("%ld\n",e1+e2+e3);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes it is. What have you tried yet?

Comment: Just add an `if` condition after the `scanf` to check for the value input by the user.

Comment: You mean at *entry* time? or at *validation* time? The latter is an if-else away, the former is gonna end up being more trouble than its worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your upper limit, 10,000,000,000 (ten billion), is quite a large number. It won't fit in a 32-bit unsigned integer, you need something larger.

Therefore, since you know an actual number you need to support, it's best to use explicit 64-bit numbers (rather than hoping your system's `unsigned long long` is big enough).

This will require C99:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t n;

if(scanf("%" PRIu64, &n) == 1)
{
  if(n >= 1 && n <= UINT64_C(10000000000))
   printf("Great, number accepted\n");
  else
   printf("Please enter a number in range 1..10000000000\n");
}
else
  printf("Please enter a number.\n");
```

The above is not a complete program, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace:

```
scanf ("%ld",&n);
```

with something like:

```
scanf ("%lu", &n);
while ((n < 1) || (n > 10 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000)) {
    printf ("No! That won't do, try again!\n");
    scanf ("%lu", &n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Not directly anyway, with one exception: Allowing signed or unsigned values b y using the formats `"%lu"` for unsigned values and `"%ld"` for signed.

For checking if the input is withing limits, you have to read the input, check it against your limits, and if outside then ask the user again.